# DNS Error On BlackBerry Simulator and Phone

Tags: java, http, blackberry, ksoap2

Hey all, having a little trouble here with connecting my application on BB. I'm using ksoap2 to call a java webservice i made running on GlassFish 3. On the simulator when i call this url

"http://equilibrio-120:8088/SocialVoiceServer/SocialServerWSService"

everything works well and it connects, the web service is currently running on my own computer. But if i append ";deviceside=true" to the url it will fail giving me a DNS Error. Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"deviceside=true" tells the connection to use DirectTCP which goes over the cell phone carrier's network.  Since the service is running on your local computer the blackberry will need to be connected to that network so append the URL with ";interface=wifi" to use your wi-fi network.  Alternatively, you could host the web service somewhare that is accessible to the internet.